# Internal API Replacement in Java 11

Tags: java, swing, graphics, migration, java-11

Can someone tell me the replacement of below listed API

```
SunToolkit.getContainingWindow

SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics

SwingUtilities2.stringWidth

SwingUtilities2.drawString

SwingUtilities2.clipStringIfNecessary

SwingUtilities2.setLeadAnchorWithoutSelection

DefaultLookup.getIcon
```

And below listed classes

```
sun.font.FontUtilities
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifComboBoxUI
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifScrollBarUI
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsScrollBarUI 
com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal_it
```

Comment: `getFontMetrics`, `stringWidth`, `drawString` technically could be done via `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`

Comment: `DefaultLookup.getIcon` - Have you looked at `UIManager`?

Comment: Why do you assume there has to be a replacement for your sake? You were never supposed to use these methods in the first place.

Comment: @MadProgrammer indeed, these methods exist for two decades now, but why use these methods of the official API, when we can use an implementation internal method unnecessarily wrapping the call?

Comment: @Holger Because at some point in time, despite what people think, those "internal" APIs can and will change - better to take the advice of the APIs which documented their "unrecommended" use or "for internal use only"

Comment: @MadProgrammer if someone sees calling an unnecessary wrapper method as an attractive option, the chance of breaking in the future gives another nice extra. Or, in other words, I thought the sarcasm was obvious.

Comment: @Holger That's my default setting 

Comment: @Holger I know, I shouldn't use these Internal API. But, in my existing project it was already used. I cannot skip/ignore these and i have to find the solution for this. Then you please tell, what will be your action on this API for the existing project?

Comment: As said, most of these methods are trivial wrappers around another method call that you can use in the first place. E.g. `getFontMetrics(JComponent c, Graphics g)` simply does `c.getFontMetrics(g.getFont())`. Likewise, `stringWidth(JComponent c, FontMetrics fm, String string)` is just `fm.stringWidth(string)` in 99% of all cases. The actual question is, when you don’t know, what these methods do or how they differ from the documented official API methods, why did you ever decided to use these methods. MadProgrammer already pointed at `Graphics` and `UIManager`.

Comment: @Holger Exactly same i did now. But my doubt is, g.getFontMetrics() and c.getFontMetrics both are there then which one I should use. Likewise stringWidth, i can get if from fm.StringWidth(String) but SwingUtilities2 used createTextLayout like this many other methods. So does fm.stringWidth will return same value as SwingUtilies2.stringWidth() and same for drawString() also. If the results are same then i don't have any problem to implement this

Comment: Well, `SwingUtilities2` did call `c.getFontMetrics`, so simply do the same to get the same behavior. In the end, these methods will do exactly the same in the intended use cases. The standard API method `SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(…)` will just delegate to the `SwingUtilities2.stringWidth(…)`, so I suppose, it will suit your needs. As said, it will end up at `fm.stringWidth(string)` in 99% of all cases. The text layout thing will only be used if a magic key tells the method that numeric glyph shaping should be used; I don’t know if mortal programmers ever encounter this scenario…

Answer (score 9):

I got the link about SwingUtilities2. Please refer the below links.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132119

```
SwingUtilities2.stringWidth
SwingUtilities2.drawString
SwingUtilities2.clipStringIfNecessary
```

These above methods can be replaced by `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicGraphicsUtils`

```
BasicGraphicsUtils.stringWidth
BasicGraphicsUtils.drawString
BasicGraphicsUtils.getClippedString
```